# SignalR ping returns error 400: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client"

Tags: javascript, ajax, signalr

The `ping` method of Microsoft's SignalR library seems to attach a random number to the URL it calls. This leads to an error 400: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client".

The auto-generated URL is: https://myProject.url/signalr/signalr/ping&_=1643826682616

Is there a way to prevent SignalR from attaching this random number? Or have I missed any required setting?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update my client-side npm package `signalr-asp-net`. I still had version 1.0.0 and updated to 1.0.3.